# Optimizing getting data from REST API calls (more than 100)

Tags: c#, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to make lots of calls from my server to a REST API that is exposed by another server but the code is taking too long to run.

Below is the code which takes a lot of time.  Right now I am using  C# `Async/Await` along with `HTTPClient`, is there a better way I can do this?

```
    static async Task RunAsync()
            {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(URL);

                foreach (var workbk in (workbooksforuserresultingMessage.Items[1] as workbookListType).workbook)
                {

                    if (workbk.project.name == "Ascend")
                    {

                            tsResponse viewresultingMessage = null;
                            //Get View Data 

                            HttpRequestMessage viewrequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "sites/" + ((siteresultingMessage.Items[0] as siteType).id.ToString()) + "/workbooks/" + workbk.id + "/views");

                            // Add our custom headers
                            viewrequestMessage.Headers.Add("X-Tableau-Auth", (resultingMessage.Items[0] as credentialsType).token.ToString());


                            HttpResponseMessage viewrequestMessageresponse = await client.SendAsync(viewrequestMessage);
                            if (viewrequestMessageresponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                            {
                                var viewresponsecontent = await viewrequestMessageresponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                                XmlSerializer siteserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(tsResponse));

                                using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(viewresponsecontent))
                                {
                                   viewresultingMessage = (tsResponse)siteserializer.Deserialize(reader);
                                }
                            }

                    }
                }

                foreach (var workbk in (workbooksforuserresultingMessage.Items[1] as workbookListType).workbook)
                {

                    if (workbk.project.name == "Ascend")
                    {

                        foreach (var vu in workbk.views)
                        {
                            tsResponse viewImageresultingMessage = null;
                            //Get View Data 

                            HttpRequestMessage viewImagerequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "sites/" + ((siteresultingMessage.Items[0] as siteType).id.ToString()) + "/workbooks/" + workbk.id + "/views/" + vu.id + "/previewImage");

                            // Add our custom headers
                            viewImagerequestMessage.Headers.Add("X-Tableau-Auth", (resultingMessage.Items[0] as credentialsType).token.ToString());


                            HttpResponseMessage viewImagewrequestMessageresponse = await client.SendAsync(viewImagerequestMessage);
                            if (viewImagewrequestMessageresponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                            {
                                var viewImageresponsecontent = await viewImagewrequestMessageresponse.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

                                XmlSerializer siteserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(tsResponse));

                                using (var ms = new MemoryStream(viewImageresponsecontent))
                                {
                                    Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
                                    //return returnImage;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
}
```

Comment: Have you increased the number of connections to that server? Look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint.aspx "ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint Method") and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.servicepoint.connectionlimit.aspx "ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit Property"). I think you can change it in the config file, but I don't recall where.

Answer (score 0):

Those 'await's inside your loop will serialize the requests.  Consider instead using .ContinueWith on the task to do some work with the result, keep track of the tasks in an array, then call Task.WhenAll once you're done setting up all the parallel work.

Answer (score 0):

AS @TheESJ said the awaits make your code execute in a serial fashion. That is once execution reaches the first `await`, execution is effectively "paused" and will not resume until that `Task` is complete. You can avoid this by not awaiting the  `Task`, just add it to a list of tasks to keep track of.

To facilitate this I think it will help if you introduced a couple of helper methods to execute the body of your loops and return a `Task`.

```
public Task<tsResponse> GetViewString(HttpRequestMessage viewrequestMessage)
   {     
        tsResponse viewresultingMessage = null;

        HttpResponseMessage viewrequestMessageresponse = await client.SendAsync(viewrequestMessage);
        if (viewrequestMessageresponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var viewresponsecontent = await viewrequestMessageresponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            XmlSerializer siteserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(tsResponse));

            using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(viewresponsecontent))
            {
               viewresultingMessage = (tsResponse)siteserializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }
        }

        return viewresultingMessage;
   }

   public Task<tsResponse> GetViewImage(HttpRequestMessage viewImagerequestMessage)
   {     
        tsResponse viewImageresultingMessage = null;
        //Get View Data 

        HttpResponseMessage viewImagewrequestMessageresponse = await client.SendAsync(viewImagerequestMessage);
        if (viewImagewrequestMessageresponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var viewImageresponsecontent = await viewImagewrequestMessageresponse.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

            XmlSerializer siteserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(tsResponse));

            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(viewImageresponsecontent))
            {
                return Image.FromStream(ms);                
            }
        }
   }
```

Then in your main loop you just add the tasks to a list as the methods are kicked off, this will essentially execute the tasks in parallel. You may need to increase the number of concurrent connections your server can make if it causes a problem. Your main method then becomes.

```
 static async Task RunAsync()
  {
      HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
      client.BaseAddress = new Uri(URL);

      var tasks = new List<Task<tsResponse>>();

      foreach (var workbk in (workbooksforuserresultingMessage.Items[1] as workbookListType).workbook)
      {
          if (workbk.project.name == "Ascend")
          {

                  tsResponse viewresultingMessage = null;
                  //Get View Data 

                  HttpRequestMessage viewrequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "sites/" + ((siteresultingMessage.Items[0] as siteType).id.ToString()) + "/workbooks/" + workbk.id + "/views");

                  // Add our custom headers
                  viewrequestMessage.Headers.Add("X-Tableau-Auth", (resultingMessage.Items[0] as credentialsType).token.ToString());

                 tasks.Add(GetViewString(viewrequestMessage);
          }
      }

      foreach (var workbk in (workbooksforuserresultingMessage.Items[1] as workbookListType).workbook)
      {

          if (workbk.project.name == "Ascend")
          {

              foreach (var vu in workbk.views)
              {
                  tsResponse viewImageresultingMessage = null;
                  //Get View Data 

                  HttpRequestMessage viewImagerequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "sites/" + ((siteresultingMessage.Items[0] as siteType).id.ToString()) + "/workbooks/" + workbk.id + "/views/" + vu.id + "/previewImage");

                  // Add our custom headers
                  viewImagerequestMessage.Headers.Add("X-Tableau-Auth", (resultingMessage.Items[0] as credentialsType).token.ToString());

                  tasks.Add(GetViewImage(viewImagerequestMessage);
              }
          }
      }

      // wait for all the tasks to complete (non blocking)
      await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```